# change paper size in microsoft report viewer

Tags: reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I have a report rdlc (microsoft report viewer 2010) which is needed to print in A3 or A4,

My question are as following

1) is it possible to change Paper size (A3 or A4) in runtime?

2) According to the paper size is it possible to make Tablix Width 100% of the paper size?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Change Paper Size at runtime:**

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings AlmostA4 = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
AlmostA4.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("CustomType", 17, 12);
ReportViewer.SetPageSettings(AlmostA4);
```

As for changing it to A3 and A4 exactly, you'll have to search around a bit more. MSDN libraries are pretty informative.

**2. "According to the paper size, is it possible to make Tablix Width 100% of the paper size?"**

This would be a matter of report creation. You would/should simply
    need to just make the tablix the size of the entire report in the
    report designer. Then set the report to not have
    margins/headers/footers then the tablix (ideally) should be the size
    of the entire sheet.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use installed paper size's in your system*

```
PageSettings a4 = new PageSettings();
foreach (PaperSize item in a4.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes)
{
    if (item.PaperName == "A4")
    {
        a4.PaperSize = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is this which provide you paper size name and their size's
[check this image for clear understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Qsj.png)