# Crystal Reports, how to, change paper size at runtime?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

`version: Crystal Reports XI  (11.0.0.895)`, not the Visual Studio version.

Our thick client application that calls our `rpt files` has printer settings, but I can override that with settings in the rpt file.  Like turning the page to landscape for printing out wide data.  We do that by dropping in formula called "Landscape" and setting that to "True".

Addition to that I need to be able to toggle between letter size and legal size based on the amount of data being demanded.  I've dug with Google for answers, but I keep finding custom paper sizes (don't need) and solutions for the Visual Studio version where I would have access to the code-behind files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in crystal reports to change the page size in run time. You need fix the page before developing the reports.

Answer (score 0):

Paper size is always fix at design-time and you are always able to change at runtime by vs, not from crystal report inside.

So only option to change any size from visual studio. You can set any standarad size or custom-size ( Before apply , define paper-size).

[change paper size in microsoft report viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738745/change-paper-size-in-microsoft-report-viewer)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/133694/Crystal-report-page-size

Answer (score 0):

Better way Create a Paperform ,to create a Paperform you can find a class in GitHub  and use the Paperform name in the crystal report
while running the program change the size of the Paperform according to your requirements, each time you have to delete the PaperForm and re-generate it again